# Undefined index: first_name error from Facebook using socialite

Tags: php, facebook, laravel

I have a Facebook login in my website and it works well in wamp at my local development. Today I uploaded it to DigitalOcean with forge so I created a new Facebook app and made all the changes but when I try to login I get this weird error, "Undefined index: first_name".

Basically my code stops working after this statement:

```
 $money = Socialize::with('facebook')->user();
```

In the Facebook Provider file I have this code:

```
protected function mapUserToObject(array $user)
{  
    return (new User)->setRaw($user)->map([
        'id' => $user['id'], 'nickname' => null, 'name' => $user['first_name'].' '.$user['last_name'],
        'email' => isset($user['email']) ? $user['email'] : null, 'avatar' => $this->graphUrl.'/'.$this->version.'/'.$user['id'].'/picture?type=normal',
    ]);
}
```

What I don't understand is how come it works locally but not in production? Could it be because I'm using an IP as the URL?
I have of course updated the app ID and secret key.

Comment: try var_dump($user); die(); before your return statement and check the values. And can you share code of your map function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what I just did is I switched to an old Facebook app that I had and now it works, I think the problem was somehow related to the new app, maybe a new version with changes.

Comment: Not “maybe”, but _definitively_ – now not “all” fields are returned any more by default, but only those that you specifically ask for using the `fields` parameter; and this is of course mentioned in the change log, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_changes

Comment: My code wasn't wrong, I just had to update socialite and now it works with the new app version.